# create a new contract in solidity

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I have a called contract, and a calling contract. The calling contract needs to create the called contract on the fly. It should be easy to do by
`CalledContract c = new CalledContract()`
in your solidity code. However, the complication is that the called contract also uses a library, and the trufflesuite will complain that the library needs to be linked before I can create a new called contract on the fly in the calling contract body.

Comment: A library? What library?

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the link before you run migrations and deploy the contracts?

something like below?

```
// 3 files
contractA.sol
contractB.sol
library.sol

// your migration file, #_something.js
import "contractA.sol";
import "contractB.sol";
import "library.sol";


module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(library_name);
    deployer.autolink();
    deployer.deploy(contractA);
    deployer.deploy(contractB);
};
```